# Prove that $h$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity

> Fix $n$. Let $A$ be the space of sequences with the elements in the set $\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$.
>
> Define $h:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ by $\displaystyle h(\{x_0,x_1,...\})=\frac{x_0}{n}+\frac{x_1}{n^2}+...$. Prove that $h$ is continuous.

$h$ is clearly surjective. For continuity I was thinking of showing that given a neighbourhood at some point $y$ in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ the preimage also contains a neighbourhood in $A$ around $h^{-1}(y)$. But how do I define a neighbourhood in $A$?

Comment: I think you mean $h:A\rightarrow \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Yep, Sorry about that.

Comment: Very likely you should view $A$ as an infinite product of $n$-element discrete spaces and give it the product topology, But I can't say for sure given the limited amount of context you have provided.